# regex in mysql update statement, convert to lowercase

Tags: mysql, regex, lowercase

i'd like to update a table field in my mysql data base and convert all links to lowercase, e.g.

to convert:

```
http://www.domamain.com/MyLinks/News/FileName.html
```

to

```
http://www.domamain.com/mylinks/news/filename.html
```

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Should be possible, at least there's some documentation about it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an entire column to lowercase with the LOWER() function

```
UPDATE mytable
SET url = LOWER(url)
```

It seems that you can't do regular expression replace in MYSQL though:
[How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: Hmmm, would that also work if table field contains other data too and not only url? Like article that contains some text, couple of links and so on?